# Python 2.7 - Program only using one line out of x amount

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to get my program to accept multiple lines, but at the moment it's picking the last line, and just converting that to pig latin. I believe it's this part of the code, but I don't know exactly what to change.

```
def pig_word(string):
    for line in text:
        line = line.split()
    lines = []
    for line in string.split('\n'):
        new_string = ""
        for word in line.split():
            first_letter = word[0]
            if first_letter in vowels:
                 new_string += word + "way" + " "
            else:
                 new_string += word[1:] + first_letter + "ay" + " "
                 global new_string
            lines.append(new_string)
```

The complete code is:

```
vowels = ("A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u")



# Functions

def pig_word(string):
    for line in text:
        line = line.split()
    lines = []
    for line in string.split('\n'):
        new_string = ""
        for word in line.split():
            first_letter = word[0]
            if first_letter in vowels:
                 new_string += word + "way" + " "
            else:
                 new_string += word[1:] + first_letter + "ay" + " "
                 global new_string
            lines.append(new_string)



def line_counter(s):
    line_count = 0
    for _ in s.split("\n"):
        line_count += 1
    return line_count

def word_counter(line):
    word_count = 0
    list_of_words = line.split()
    word_count += len(list_of_words)
    return word_count

# File path conversion
text = raw_input("Enter the path of a text file: ")
file_path = open(text, "r")
out_file = open("pig_output.txt", "w")


s = file_path.read()
pig = pig_word(s)
out_file.write(str(new_string)+ "\n")
out_file.write("\n")


linecount = line_counter(s)
wordcount = word_counter(s)


file_path.close()
out_file.close()

# Results

print "\n\n\n\nTranslation finished and written to pig_output.txt"
print "A total of {} lines were translated successfully.".format(linecount)
print "A total of {} words were translated successfully.".format(wordcount)
print "\n\n\n\n"
```

The input file contains:

```
Pig latin
I dont know what is wrong with this
Random testing
Randomly typing
```

Output file is:

```
andomlyRay ypingtay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there are several inconsistencies and weird constructs; just looking at the most obvious issues, change your `pig_word` as:

```
def pig_word(string):
    lines = []
    for line in string.split('\n'):
        new_string = ""
        for word in line.split():
            first_letter = word[0]
            if first_letter in vowels:
                 new_string += word + "way" + " "
            else:
                 new_string += word[1:] + first_letter + "ay" + " "
            lines.append(new_string)
    return lines
```

then at the bottom of the script, where you save the output:

```
out_file.write('\n'.join(pig))
```

There would be other things to discuss on your code, but this should fix the biggest issue.

Answer (score 0):

You use the global variable `new_string` to print out the result. This variable contains only one line, therefore, at the end of the for-loop, the last line. Return the variable `lines`, which is at the moment unused, and use this list to print out every line:

```
def pig_word(string):
    lines = []
    for line in string.split('\n'):
        new_line = []
        for word in line.split():
            first_letter = word[0]
            if first_letter in vowels:
                 new_line.append(word + "way")
            else:
                 new_line.append(word[1:] + first_letter)
        lines.append(' '.join(new_line))
    return lines
```